# Regex delete linebreak

Tags: notepad++, regex, linebreaks

I have a file in which I want to remove only certain line breaks, such as this example:

```
ProduceFalse:
Return a Boolean of value "false"

ProduceTrue:
Return a Boolean of value "true"
```

In the above example I would like to replace the line breaks after the `:` characters, so that the file looks like this:

```
ProduceFalse: Return a Boolean of value "false"

ProduceTrue: Return a Boolean of value "true"
```

To do that, I opened the file with Notepad++ and used the replace function with regular expressions. I can find occurences of these cases with the expression `:[\r\n]` perfectly, but replacing it with `:` seems to have no effect on the line break.

How can I remove a line break which I have found this way - or what would be a better way to do so (preferably in Notepad++ or with another editor's replace function, since I would love to use it under Windows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `:\K\R`
- Replace with: `1 space`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
:       : a semicolon
\K      : forget all we have seen until this position
\R      : any kind of linebreak
```